# How can I find the definition of a user-defined CMake function using CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm generating a build tree for someone's project using their CMakeLists.txt, which contains a reference to a user-defined function. Unfortunately, the referenced source-tree is huge, and it's not clear to me where the function is defined.

Does `cmake` provide a means of discovering and printing the location of user-defined cmake function definitions?

If not, I'll just use another program to search for it, but I'm curious. It doesn't seem to be included with `--system-information`, but maybe there's another option that includes this sort of information.

Comment: You could run CMake in a trace mode, where it prints all commands, including the `function` commands which define functions. Using `grep` or other processing tools for that trace you could find the needed function's definition. See that my answer about parsing CMake trace output in json format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76315014/3440745.

Comment: @Tsyvarev --trace does the trick! Please feel free to post as an answer with any links to other relevant posts.